# how to consider delimiter(,) as a text in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, etl, msbi

i got the requirement from one of my client.

the requirement is

source is a delimiter flat file  and delimiter is comma(,). source data contain the comma within the data.now i want to consider that delimiter also text. here is the example source file
ex:

```
col1,col2,col3

10,usa,uk,hr

20,ind,aus,fin

30,europe,marketing
```

now my output should be like  this

[image]

without using script task i need to achieve this output remaining transformations

thanks in advance

the following screen shots shows the my trials[image: this is flatfile preview after configuration]

[image: at last out put came like this]

Comment: How could you tell it is 10 usa,uk hr and not 10 usa uk,hr ?

Comment: @Ndech  they specified col3 have only one value like that..then only we come to know usa,uk not uk,hr  i hope you understand

Comment: Ok. It should be pretty easy to do with a script task, why don't you want to go that way ?

Comment: @Ndech iam not good in coding .i don't no how to do and the client also asking with out using any code we need to implement.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without scripting. Change the input file delimiter or use a text qualifier so text data would appear like this `10,"Usa,uk","hr"`

Comment: If possible to ask the client to change it to `|` pipe delimited file, as pipe is hardly used in any sentences compare to comma.

Comment: @PPRas'd, your source file example above contains no quotes, however, the data view screen shot shows quotes in the strings. Where did these quotes come from? :-) Did you add them via SSIS or are these contained in the source file?

Comment: @Ben Gribaudo one of our member said ..please see the answer one .after that only i modified my source data. :)

Comment: You can load the data as is into one a column staging table then process it in the staging table. It requires T-SQL rather than script if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes as the text qualifier.  i.e.

```
"20","ind,aus","fin"
"30","europe,"marketing"
```

The text qualifier can be defined in the flat file connection manager.  I think else is just guess work and you will code be writing break fix code to handle new scenarios from now until doomsday.

Comment: @PPRas'd : Can u provide the screen shots, after trying what mark has Suggested.

Comment: @satish Please check the screen shots i have updated my question :)

Comment: @PPRas'd could you show the first page of the flat file manager where you would configure the text qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that the 1st and 3rd fields always have a single value, and everything in between belongs to the 2nd field, you can use a regex. Any etl tool should allow you to parse a csv file via regexes.

The following

```
([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*)
```

works on the 4 examples you mention.

I'm not a regex expert, I'm sure you can make it much more solid and elegant.

Comment: if i use regex i go for script task. my problem is without using script task i need to achieve this.

Comment: You can easily develop a Pentaho Data Integration task for this: a CSV file input step reads each line, a RegEx step matches parts of the line to fields and then you're free to output that to a DB of your choosing. But, regardless of what you choose, there will almost certainly be a regex component somewhere parsing you lines. You have a varying format. Anything that is not fixed width or delimited will have to parse a pattern somehow.